# Stop JBoss EAP 7.2 Server Group via HTTP API

Tags: jboss

I can stop my server group using the JBoss 7.2 CLI:

```
jboss_cli -c "/server-group=MyServerGroup :stop-servers(blocking=true)"
```

How can I do this over the HTTP REST API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stop servers:

```
curl --digest http://localhost:9990/management --header "Content-Type: application/json" -u user:password -d '{"address":[{"server-group":"MyServerGroup"}],"operation":"stop-servers","blocking":true}'
```

Start servers:

```
curl --digest http://localhost:9990/management --header "Content-Type: application/json" -u user:password -d '{"address":[{"server-group":"MyServerGroup"}],"operation":"start-servers"}'
```